# String buffer - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am having string buffer variable which holds the input i read from a file. Some cases i am getting input file in huge size. In those cases i am getting the OutOfMemoryError.

Here is my code:

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer("");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Kindly help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which ide do you use?

Comment: it is not a good idea to load the entire contents of a file into your memory.
What purpose do you want to solve by loading everything into memory?Can u explain the use case

Comment: Either buy more memory, or, process your file line by line.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer when you can use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either read the input in chunks, or change the `-Xmx` parameter (maximum memory size) in your JVM to a larger size.

Comment: The second option calling the java class with -Xmx has worked for me. Hope it won't cause any memory issues. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If the file you are processing is huge, you may need to find a way to do that processing on the fly instead of reading the whole file into a `StringBuffer` in memory. Depending on how the data is structured, this might be performing some action for each line read in, or every several lines.

Answer (score 0):

A further alternative would be to only hold an index of the file in memory. It depends what you want to do with it.

If, for example, you wish to display the file contents on screen, you could open the file for random access and scan through it, recording the offset of the beginning of each line in the file. You could then access each line individually by looking up the line in your index, seeking to the indicated location and reading from there.